# LCD1602A displaying blocks

Tags: arduino-uno

I am having an issue with the LCD1602A and Arduino Uno. I have followed a tutorial on youtube that has got the device working, however the LCD is only displaying white blocks in all 16 segments of the top row.

[image: Failure Image]

Pin Out

LCD

- VSS -> GND on Breadboard
- VDD ->  5V on Breadboard
- V0  -> Connected to 5K potentiometer
- RS  -> Pin 1 on Arduino Uno
- RW  -> GND on Breadboard
- E   -> Pin 2 on Arduino Uno
- D0  -> Not Connected
- D1  -> Not Connected
- D2  -> Not Connected
- D3  -> Not Connected
- D4  -> Pin 7 on Arduino
- D5  -> Pin 6 on Arduino
- D6  -> Pin 5 on Arduino
- D7  -> Pin 4 on Arduino
- A   ->  5V on Breadboard
- K   -> GND on Breadboard

Code

```c
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7); // Creates an LC object. Parameters: (rs, enable, d4, d5, d6, d7) 
void setup() { 
 lcd.begin(16,2); // Initializes the interface to the LCD screen, and specifies the dimensions (width and height) of the display } 
}
void loop() { 
 lcd.print("Arduino"); // Prints "Arduino" on the LCD 
 delay(3000); // 3 seconds delay 
 lcd.setCursor(2,1); // Sets the location at which subsequent text written to the LCD will be displayed 
 lcd.print("12345"); 
 delay(3000); 
 lcd.clear(); // Clears the display 
 lcd.blink(); //Displays the blinking LCD cursor 
 delay(4000); 
 lcd.setCursor(7,1); 
 delay(3000); 
 lcd.noBlink(); // Turns off the blinking LCD cursor 
 lcd.cursor(); // Displays an underscore (line) at the position to which the next character will be written 
 delay(4000); 
 lcd.noCursor(); // Hides the LCD cursor 
 lcd.clear(); // Clears the LCD screen 
}
```

Now the program compiles and uploads OK the potentiometer dims the blocks perfectly fine.

However it is supposed to print Arduino and 12345 and I am unsure why.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check your contrast Settings.

Comment: Checked contrast settings using potentiometer no luck. These only dim the blocks.

Comment: Your pin out text does not match the pin assigment in the `lcd()` line.
Should be `LiquidCrystal lcd(1,2,7,6,5,4)`, e.g., your data wires are flipped.

Comment: Thanks for your help.